# Ao usar setupWithViewPager perco os títulos das abas

Tags: android

Tenho um tablayout que nele contém uma ViewPager, e possuo dois fragments. Quando eu trocava de tela clicando na aba1 ou aba2, por exemplo, ele trocava a aba normal, porém quando eu usava o arrasto de dedo para ir para a outra tela, ele trocava a tela, mas o indicator do tablayout permanecia inalterado.

Por exemplo eu estava na aba2 e o indicator estava indicado na aba1. Para corrigir isso usei o `setupWithViewPager(viewPager)`, assim o indicator muda conforme eu arrasto o dedo pelas abas.

O problema é que quando uso este atributo os títulos das abas somem. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Coloque o código do seu PageAdapter.

Comment: Utilize o campo de respostas para explicar como se resolve o problema e não para deixar comentários. Faça um [tour] para conhecer um pouco melhor o funcionamento do site.